# Why Vertical centering needed

Tags: ios, iphone

[image]

In the below story board I add the horizontal spacing between the labels and Text fields. But when I run it on the screen no data is shown on the label. So What I did was add the vertical centering on the Label. Then it works. But I need to know why horizontal spacing between labels and text fields is not enough to show layout on the simulator perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to specify the horizontal spacing only. Would you, as a human being, be able to draw something on a canvas if I told you its horizontal spacing only? You wouldn't.

The constraints of a view must define both the size and the position of that view. You have many options to do that.

For example, to define the width of a label you can give it a width constraint or pin it from both left and right side to other views.

Answer (score 0):

Every UI element to appear correctly needs x,y,width and height constraints

when you constraint the label with horizental constraint to the textfield you denfine the x-axis , but what about the y ? should autolayout place it top , bottom , centerY or top with 30pts or bottom with 20 pts or where , which make the process vague

autolayout need to know eactly where to place the element as those constraints will be translated to x,y values

> X=> leading , trailing , centerX
>
> Y=> Top , bottom , centerY
>
> Width => static (such as 30 or 50) or proportional ( such as half of screen width)
>
> Height => static (such as 30 or 50) or propertional ( such as half of screen height)

For the `UILabel`/`UIButton` setting the width and height is optional because both of them has an intrinsic content size , meaning that they will resize according to the text setted to them